# Loop for web scraping having multiple issues

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am having an issue with my R code to download box scores from a website.

```
for (i in Sites) {
try({log("a")}, silent=TRUE)
webpage_url <- i
webpage <- xml2::read_html(webpage_url)

table <- rvest::html_table(webpage, fill=TRUE)[[1]]
  
}
#Here's an example url
"https://www.baseball-almanac.com/box-scores/boxscore.php?boxid=202007310COL"
```

The sites data frame contains the URLs I have that need to be **scraped**. I tried to make a loop that would replace change the last 8 or so digits of the URL but I could not get that to work either. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1. What exactly does `Sites` contain? Does it contain the entire URL (`https://www.baseball-almanac.com/box-scores/boxscore.php?boxid=202007310COL`) or just the number at the end (`202007310COL`) ? 2. `html_table` on that page returns 5 tables, what data do you want to extract? How would your output look?

Comment: It contains the entire URLs. `library(xml2)
webpage_url <- "https://www.baseball-almanac.com/box-scores/boxscore.php?boxid=202007310COL"
webpage <- xml2::read_html(webpage_url)

table<-rvest::html_table(webpage, fill=TRUE)[[1]]
head(table)` When I run this individually, it gives me the data I need, just needs to be cleaned. I am trying to create a loop that will let me save separate data frames of each URL in the loop. My plan was to create another loop to clean the data after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the data from each url in a list.

```
extract_table <- function(webpage_url) {
  webpage <- xml2::read_html(webpage_url)  
  rvest::html_table(webpage, fill=TRUE)[[1]] 
}

list_data <- lapply(Sites, extract_table)
```

`list_data` has a list of dataframes, if you want to combine them into one dataframe use

```
data <- do.call(rbind, list_data)
```

Comment: I am getting an 'x must be a string of length 1' Any idea on how to fix this? I've tried finding a fix for this error but found no working solution.

Comment: What does `dput(head(Sites))` return?

Comment: `structure(list(ï..https...www.baseball.almanac.com.box.scores.boxscore.php.boxid.202007230COL = c("https://www.baseball-almanac.com/box-scores/boxscore.php?boxid=202007240COL", 
"https://www.baseball-almanac.com/box-scores/boxscore.php?boxid=202007250COL", 
"https://www.baseball-almanac.com/box-scores/boxscore.php?boxid=202007260COL", 
"https://www.baseball-almanac.com/box-scores/boxscore.php?boxid=202007270COL", 
"https://www.baseball-almanac.com/box-scores/boxscore.php?boxid=202007290COL"
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: It seems you have read the data incorrectly, you have URL as column name. How did you read the data? You need to include `header = FALSE` while reading the data. Also these are not complete URL because it does not have `'https'` at the beginning. After fixing the above error you might need to do `Sites[[1]] <- paste0('htttps://www.', Sites[[1]])` and then use `list_data <- lapply(Sites[[1]], extract_table)`